# How to deploy a mobile 6 application on a phone?

Tags: windows-mobile

I have made my application and I want to check it out. I made a Cab file through the smartphone cab setup wizard.

Now I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transfer this .cab to the phone by any means (ActiveSync, Flash card, Bluetooth....) and run it there via file manager.

As an alternative, if you're developing with MS Visual Studio, you can configure deployment options in your project (though defaults are OK in most cases) and hit Debug. MSVC will copy the app to the device and run it under debugger. Cab-file is not involved in this scenario. You need an ActiveSync connection.

All these methods (except Bluetooth, I think) can work with emulator as well as real device.

Comment: Thanks done that but now it says my phone is not the right version. It is Hp PAQ 110 Classic. I built my with the 6.0 Professional SDK. Can I upgrade my device to whatever version it needs(the settings say it has 6.0 on it but must not be the same version).

Comment: @chobo2 -- that is weird. WM 6.0 Pro SDK projects should be installable on WM 6.0 Classic by default... i think. Check your CAB project properties. What `OSVersionMin` and `OSVersionMax` are set to?